# Sending a gift of wine to USA

Tags: united-states, gift-tax

I sent a bottle of wine from Portugal to Connecticut, USA. This is a gift for my friend. The bottle is 0.75L and costs about 130 euros (about $140).

Will my friend pay a tax upon receiving the gift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will not be a gift tax. In the United States somebody that receives a gift doesn't pay a tax.

Each state in the US regulates alcohol. That means the state determines if alcohol can be sent from their state, sent to their state, or sent within their state. The carrier (US post office, Federal Express, United Parcel Service...) may also have their own policies regarding sending alcohol.

So if you are sending the wine from Portugal to Connecticut you need to make sure that it is legal to do so.  If you are ordering the wine from a store within Connecticut, they are aware of the laws. If you are ordering the wine from someplace else in the US, they should be aware of the regulations that apply to their state and also Connecticut laws.

Comment: Since it's coming in from out of the country, customs duty may be owed.

Comment: Some clarifications: A single bottle sent unaccompanied from outside the US to the US will require both duty and excise tax, although the amounts are trivial for a single bottle (less than a dollar). US CBP will collect that per their usual methods. Connecticut allows up to 5 gallons imported from outside the US per person per year for personal use, and has no additional tax on the import. The US Postal service isn't allowed by law to ship alcohol (but most private carriers are happy to do it).

Comment: This is not USPS, that wine shop uses something different specially for wines...If I got you right, a receiver should pay at most 1 dollar per 1 bottle upon receiving? How does US CBP collect the payments?